# Numpy method to return the index of the occurrence of an array within an array of arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of arrays that represents a set of unique colour values:

```
[[0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         1.        ]
 [0.         1.         1.        ]
 [0.5019608  0.5019608  0.5019608 ]
 [0.64705884 0.16470589 0.16470589]
 [0.9607843  0.9607843  0.8627451 ]
 [1.         0.         0.        ]
 [1.         0.84313726 0.        ]
 [1.         1.         0.        ]
 [1.         1.         1.        ]]
```

And another numpy array that represents one of the colours:

```
[0.9607843  0.9607843  0.8627451 ]
```

I need a function to find the index where the colour array occurs in the set of colours, i.e. the function should return 5 for the arrays above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**numpy.where()** returns you the exact positions in the array for values of given condition. So here, it would be as following (denoting big array as **arr1**, and the sought vector as **arr2**:

```
np.where(np.all(arr1 == arr2, axis=1))
```

Which then returns array of row indexes of sought rows.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is a relatively short list of colors (<1000), the simplest thing to do is probably just iterate over the list and compare each element of the sub-array.

```
color_list = ...
color_index = -1
target_color = [0.9607843, 0.9607843, 0.8627451]
for i in range(0, len(color_list)):
    cur_color = color_list[i]
    if (cur_color[0] == target_color[0] and cur_color[1] = target_color[1] and cur_color[2] = target_color[2]):
        color_index = i
        break
```